# sender object - с#

Tags: c#, frameworks

so how do i get an sender object to interact with it?

```cs
private system.Windows.Forms.Label objT ;

this.LabelsProcess.MouseClick += (s, e) => choose_process(s, e);

private void choose_process(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  var obj = ((Label)sender).Name;
  objT = obj;
}
private void outher_func()
{
  objT.Text = "Some text";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error with this code?

Comment: Should this be: `objT.Name = obj;`

Comment: yes - Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Comment: I think you want `var obj = ((Label)sender)`. So now your Label object is in the `var obj` and you can interact with it. As it is, you are just getting it's name.

Comment: thanks, i found the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `sender` of the `MouseClick` event handler of the `LabelProcess` out of its scope you should set the `objT` with the `sender` casted to `Label`:

```
tobjT = (Label)sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void choose_process(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   Label obj = (Label)sender; // this is label object
   objT = obj;              // share label object in this class 
 }
```

Comment: Maybe, or maybe they are trying to set `objT.Name`.

Comment: this not work objT.Name - because error  - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
private system.Windows.Forms.Label objT ;

this.LabelsProcess.MouseClick += (s, e) => choose_process(s, e);

private void choose_process(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  var obj = ((Label)sender);
  objT = obj;
}
private void outher_func()
{
  objT.Text = "Some text";
}
```